# upgrading TFS 2012 from an unsupported configuration

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I have a TFS 2012 installation that was originally installed to SQL server 2012.  Later on we upgraded SQL Server to 2016 which isn't supported by TFS 2012 but still worked.  I wanted to take a  clone of the VM and copy the database over to an SQL Express instance to simulate the upgrade, however it won't let me connect to the new database saying the configuration is unsupported.  I tried upgrading TFS to 2015 but because the database wasn't connected during the upgrade there are still elements in the database that identify it as TFS 2012 and it won't let me attach to it.

What would be the best strategy to get back to an environment where I can upgrade?  I tried doing a scripted export of the database to downgrade it to SQL Express 2012 but that failed as well.

Comment: 1. You cannot connect sql 2016 with TFS2012, Azure DevOps Server installations is “bound” to a specific version of SQL Server, you can check the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020#azure-sql-database-and-sql-server

2. When you upgrade to TFS2015, did you take the production server offline using TFSServiceControl's quiesce command? Please check the upgrade guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/walkthrough?view=tfs-2015#do-the-upgrade

Comment: We installed TFS 2012 to a stand alone SQL 2012 Standard server when we originally set it up.  Then someone upgraded SQL 2012 to SQL 2016 without investigating whether the underlying applications supported that upgrade.  So now I'm in this unsupported configuration tasked with upgrading to TFS 2015.  I was able to clone the TFS server, SQL server, and primary DC to create an environment to stage the upgrade.  In this environment I was able to run the upgrade to TFS 2015 successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clone the TFS server, SQL server, and primary DC to create an environment to stage the upgrade. In this environment I was able to run the upgrade to TFS 2015 successfully.

One hiccup I did run into was we were using FIPS.  I had to disable FIPS in order to configure after upgrading.